# Что есть Disposable Pattern?

Tags: c#

Изучаю теоретические вопросы (52 вопроса буржуских для Сеньера) и не совсем понимаю что за паттерн такой. Понимаю что такое сборщик мусора, понимаю как он работает, понимаю его стадии работы, как то маркировка объектов, сжатие, очистка  поколения 0, далее поколение 1, и поколение 2. Можно вызвать на объекте финализатор, который будет очищать все неуправляемые ресурсы у объекта перед работой сборщика. И есть Disposable паттерн, суть которого в том, что на объекте реализуется интерфейс Idisposable, в котором вызывается один метод. И получается, суть этого паттерна только в том чтобы вызвать этот метод и сообщить сборщику мусора что объект подлежит очистке или я как ко не так все понял?

Comment: в буржунетах искали? Это же в [доках есть](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/garbage-collection/implementing-dispose)

Comment: Сборщику мусора дела нет до Dispose метода, для него имеет значение только наличие финализатора.

Comment: если говорить про интеграцию `IDisposable` в `C#` - то это только качается конструкции `using`. Конструкция `using` по сути сахар, который вам код сокращает, и всё.

Comment: @tym32167 Да я в доках смотрел но я не совсем понимаю логики,  тогда получается что, паттерн запускает как раз сборщик мусора с финализатором.

Comment: то есть вы можете не реализоввывать вовсе IDisposable, писать свой костыль `DisposeMyStuff(){....}`, который будет освобождать ресурсы, вызывать этот свой костыль из финализатора и из кода и всё будет работать.

Comment: паттерн ничего не запускает, он помогает не допускать ошибок в коде и всего то.

Comment: @tym32167 да  Using по сути это try и finaly в try  пробуем очистить ресурсы,а в finaly вызываем GC с финализатором.

Comment: нет, в finally вы вызывете Dispose метод, финализатор вызывается только сборщиком мусора в неопределенное время в процессе уничтожения объекта

Comment: @tym32167 Ну а если на вопрос что такое этот паттерн ответить,что он  позволяет не допускать ошибок и вызывать сборщик с финализатором это же будет не корректно ? Или нет

Comment: по большому счету, расчет иет такой: есть using, он позволяет освобождать ресурсы кодом программиста. Но если программист не очень, и забыл использовать using, есть финализатор, в котором тоже ижет вызов dispose.

Comment: нет, некорректно, если поглядите в паттерн, увидите, что в Dispose() методе есть строчка `GC.SuppressFinalize(this);`, что означает дословно `если прогер вызвал этот метод, то не надо этот объект финализировать, так как этот метод и так все почистит/освободит`

Comment: то есть паттерн предусматривает 2 взаимоисключающих способа освобождения захваченных ресурсов 1) вызовом dispose() ручками или юзингом с освобождением управляемых и неуправляемых ресурсрв 2) вызовом финализатора с освобождением неправляемых ресурсов

Comment: 1) вызывет сам прогер, 2) - вызывает GC, если прогер забыл вызвать первый пункт.

Comment: @MSDN.WhiteKnight тут все таки не совсем тот вопрос, тут же не про то, зачем надо `IDisposable`, а про то, что из себя представляем конкретный кусок кода - [Dispose паттерн](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/garbage-collection/implementing-dispose), реккомендованный MS - я в том ответе этот паттерн не увидел.